# php7 very slow, without config very fast

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a very confusing problem..

```
andreaspabst:~ $ time php -v
PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2017 10:05:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans

real    0m5.106s
user    0m0.065s
sys     0m0.026s
```

If I am running cli php7 it is very slow in my shell!

```
andreaspabst:~ $ time php -n -v
PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 14 2017 10:05:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.007s
```

If I am using `-n` parameter (run php without config) it is very fast!

As you can see (built: Sep 14 2017 10:05:35) I've already removed PHP and reinstalled... I already had a look here, but most solutions are for windows..

How can I get PHP fast again? What could be the problem?
Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Potential disk issues?

Comment: 63gb free disk space.. dont think so :-(

Comment: No, he is suggesting it is waiting on I/O.

Comment: `dd` is quite fast.. how can I check the speed and improve it?

Comment: php5.6.3 (the last version I had installed) was very fast by the way!

Comment: a cold 5 seconds seems like a DNS resolution error ... frequent with mDNSResponder btw.  Look in the config to see if there is in there a reference to a host that needs to be resolved. Look **[here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175320/why-is-my-hostname-resolution-taking-so-long)** to get an appreciation of this bizarro.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg this could be true! As I had the php problem I was at university in the campus wifi.. and now - as I'm at home again - it is really fast again... without any change, than my location.. is it possible, that the slow service at the university has caused my problem?

Comment: @AndreasPabst if i had to guess, their DNS resolutions tries IPv6 first, then IPv4.  That has been problematic on osX ... try to see if there is a way to force IPv4 on your box. I had to do that with php' curl , like so :           `curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE , CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`. I dunno Sierra, see if there is a way to force that at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's reading the config. That's why it's slower compared to when it doesn't

Comment: may I find out why it is _so_ slow? and how may I speed it up?

Comment: Look at `hdparm`, `IOPS`, or `dd`?

Comment: @Nikolay --  It's obviosly reading the config .. But even for NOT reading the config with the -n flag -- I'd consider .026s unreasonable.  It should be < .010 on a clean install

Comment: @ficuscr what do you mean exactly? I've never used those commands :-)

Comment: sounds like RTFM :)  FWIW: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108838/how-can-i-benchmark-my-hdd

Comment: `time sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024k of=tstfile count=1024`  is running `real 0m1.259s` and `sys sys 0m0.726s` with `1073741824 bytes transferred in 1.187439 secs (904250118 bytes/sec)`

Comment: Hmm. Changes since a clean install? Scale back modules and includes?  Add back one at a time and determine if tied to one of them? Checked for errors? It's not the version. 7.* should be faster than 5.6

Comment: I've reinstalled php7 and it's still as slow as before.. I never had any problem using php7 on my other mac! it is realy _very_ fast! but on my macbook since a few days its superslow.. What do you mean with "one at a time"?

Comment: @ficuscr RTFM seems like a XY answer : once you own a hammer , everything looks like a nail.  Most likely not a disk issue.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg not looking at the `dd` results. Only thing we know is it is faster when not parsing the .ini. I've seen imap cause this.

Comment: @ficuscr been there, done that. That delay is an mDNSResponder issue with boundary cases.  Not disk related at all.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I misread your comment, thought you were saying it was disk and my suggestion of checking specific modules was XY. The RTFM was in response to how to benchmark.

Comment: @AndreasPabst could try to load one at a time with `-d` [option](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php), or adjust your ini's - same idea though, isolate what causes the slow down.

Comment: @ficuscr `php -d` and `php -n` were both very fast! but now, you may not believe it, is everything fine again! the only thing that has changed is the internet connection from slow (at university) to fast (at home).. could this have been the issue? because of dns stuff?

Comment: Yes, what @YvesLeBorg has been suggesting.